# Combine mean and standard deviation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, data-science

Is there a package in Python that lets you combine means and standard deviations from multiple groups to a single group?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Let us know what your data looks like and what your desired output is on that example.

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: So, after a moment, I mean I'd like the mean of a combination of means which means the first moment of a distribution based on a combination of distributions